# JQuery Selector of input

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

So I have this table:

```
<table id = "editor">
  <tr>
  <tr class= "numberedListElement>
     <td name = "aaa" ... .</td>
     <td name = "b" ... .</td>
     <td class="iconsType" title="Numbered list element">
         <div class="iconsDiv">
            <input type="button" class="numberedList1" title="nl" id="numberedL">
            **<input type="button" class="numberedList1b" title="list" id="numbL">**
            <input type="button" class="bulletList1" title="nl" id="bulletL">
          </div>
         <input type="button" class="letteredList1" title="ll" id="letteredL"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
 </table>
```

So I need to select and delete that input.

I tried this :

```
$('#editor tr.numberedListElement td:last-child input')
```

but it returns blank.

Comment: what the problem if you have ID`s of elements? $("#letteredL").remove()

Comment: You have an extra `<tr>` element in there. I'm not sure that is what you intended to do.

Comment: The problem is you forgot `"` at the end of class attr. `<tr class="numberedListElement">` should fix but consider Lix's answer.

Comment: @deadulya you are right, but i have multiple such tr-s <tr class= "numberedListElement> with the same id-s. I need somehow to generate them uniquely. Thanks

Comment: @alex1111 so you can identified you needed tr $(".numberedListElement") and then find you id in it $(".numberedListElement")[5].find("#letteredL"). it is not very good style coding, cause ID`s must be unique, if they are not you should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do here would be to access the element directly using the [`id` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

> **Description**: Selects a single element with the given id attribute.

The code would look like this:

```
$( "#numbL" ).remove();
```

`id` attributes need to be unique so you can use it safely to remove only this element without worrying about affecting anything else.

Comment: I have multiple such tr-s <tr class= "numberedListElement> with the same id-s. So i need a way to select the second input from the last td from the tr with class numberedListElement... So it can affect all

Comment: As I have mentioned already, your `id` attributes are **required** to be unique. You should only have one occurrence of any one `id` value.

Comment: Which input do you want to remove? As @Lix has said, elements can easily be removed by ID ... but your HTML has to be valid - no duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

try which is not so generic:

```
     $("#editor > tr:nth(1) > td:nth(2) > input:nth(1)");
```

anyways, use last and not last-child

Answer (score -1):

I can see you have a TR element inside another TR element.. if you remove that, it might work.